# Assigning 2 IPv4 blocks to one interface

Tags: debian, nic, ipv4, interface

I have been assigned these 2 blocks by my provider

```
Block: x.x.x.184/29
Usable range: x.x.x.186 - x.x.x.190
Gateway: x.x.x.185
Subnet: 255.255.255.248
```

And

```
Block: x.x.x.192/29
Usable range: x.x.x.194 - x.x.x.198
Gateway: x.x.x.193
Subnet: 255.255.255.248
```

I am wanting to assign both those blocks to one machine.

I currently have this config working for the first block:

```
iface eth0 inet static
        address x.x.x.186
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        network x.x.x.184
        broadcast x.x.x.191
        gateway x.x.x.185
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        dns-search blahblah

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address x.x.x.187
  netmask 255.255.255.248
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address x.x.x.188
  netmask 255.255.255.248
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address x.x.x.189
  netmask 255.255.255.248
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address x.x.x.190
  netmask 255.255.255.248
```

How would I add the second second block to this interface?

Comment: Are the Gateways on the same interface ? If yes, what holds you back to just add more aliases ?

Comment: I don't know but I'm thinking no. The `x`s in the different blocks above are different. Block 1 gateway: 123.123.123.185 block 2 gateway: 321.321.321.193

Comment: So you have more than one physical interface ?

Comment: Sorry new to all this. On the machine I want to use the IPs on I have a single interface, `eth0`.

Comment: So can I just add more aliases as I have done with the other extra IPs? The 2 different blocks have different Gateway addresses, how should I handle that?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Managed to get it working with this https://serverfault.com/questions/517948/multiple-ip-different-gateways-one-interface-debian-squeezy